# Insert Into No Duplicate from another table only inserting

Tags: mysql, sql-update, no-duplicates

I've been fighting with this for hours now. I need to build a master table from multiple tables (bad design, I know.) I've written this code:

```
INSERT INTO amdashboard
(DashboardFirst, DashboardLast, charlotteorg, charlotteAdd1, charlotteCity, charlotteState, charlotteZip, charlottey2007, charlottey2008, charlottey2009,charlottey2010, charlotteY2011, charlotteY2012)
select Firstname, lastname, org, add1, city, state, zip, y2007, y2008, y2009, y2010, y2011, y2012
from CharlotteClean
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
amdashboard.DashboardFirst = CharlotteClean.Firstname,
amdashboard.DashboardLast = CharlotteClean.Lastname,
amdashboard.Charlotteorg = CharlotteClean.org,
amdashboard.Charlotteadd1 = CharlotteClean.add1,
amdashboard.Charlottecity = CharlotteClean.city,
amdashboard.Charlottestate = CharlotteClean.state,
amdashboard.Charlottezip = CharlotteClean.zip,
amdashboard.Charlottey2007 = CharlotteClean.y2007,
amdashboard.Charlottey2008 = CharlotteClean.y2008,
amdashboard.Charlottey2009 = CharlotteClean.y2009,
amdashboard.Charlottey2010 = CharlotteClean.y2010,
amdashboard.Charlottey2011 = CharlotteClean.y2011,
amdashboard.Charlottey2012 = CharlotteClean.y2012;
```

I've made DashboardFirst and DashboardLast a combined key. But whenever I run this, it only inserts, never updates, and I know that some of the records should update.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the result of this statement `DESC amdashboard`? execute that in mysql.

Comment: The return is too long. I have over 300 fields in that table.

Comment: Field Type Null Key Default Extra
ID int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
DashboardFirst varchar(100) YES MUL NULL 
DashboardLast varchar(100) YES  NULL